# Inner Join BIgquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I want to mix a couple of dimenssion from two different tables:

**Table 1**

| Person | Team | Client ID | Client | Time Spent (h) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Noah | Marketing | ECOM01 | Nike | 10 |
| Peter | Marketing | ECOM01 | Nike | 10 |

**Table 2**

| Person | Team | Client ID | Client | Time Spent (h) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | CX | ECOM01 | Nike | 10 |
| Max | CX | ECOM01 | Nike | 10 |

I am using the next query

```
SELECT 
    M.Client_ID,
    M.Client,
    SUM(C.Time_spent_h) + SUM(M.Time_spent_h) AS Total_time
FROM
    (SELECT 
        Client_ID, Client, SUM(Time_spent_h) AS Time
    FROM
        table_1
    GROUP BY 1 , 2) AS M
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        Client_ID, Client, SUM(Time_spent_h) AS Time
    FROM
        table_2
    GROUP BY 1 , 2) AS C ON C.ID = M.ID
GROUP BY 1 , 2
```

The result is the next one:

| Client ID | Client | Total_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ECOM01 | NIke | 40 |

But this is my expected output:

| Person | Team | Client ID | Client | Time Spent (h) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Noah | Marketing | ECOM01 | Nike | 10 |
| Peter | Marketing | ECOM01 | Nike | 10 |
| Alex | CX | ECOM01 | Nike | 10 |
| Max | CX | ECOM01 | Nike | 10 |

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wuld sum up all hours work by a name,team, clint_id and client namename first and then UNION, whoch is a vertical join, of two tables

```
SELECT 
       Person,  Team, Client_ID, Client, SUM(Time_spent_h) AS Time
    FROM
        table_1
    GROUP BY 1 , 2,3,4
UNION ALL    
SELECT 
       Person,  Team, Client_ID, Client, SUM(Time_spent_h) AS Time
    FROM
        table_2
    GROUP BY 1 , 2,3,4
```